# Is the series $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}$ convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}$$

What convergence test would one use for this, and how?

Comment: $\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}\to 1$, so the series can't converge.

Comment: You can use the Raabe–Duhamel's test and see that it does diverge!

Answer (score 2):

For all $n \ge 1$ we actually have
$$\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+1}} > \frac12. $$
From this it's immediate that the series doesn't converge.

Comment: While I understand and thank you for your logic, is there any way to represent that with one of the main convergence tests? It's needed to show work on one of those for a test.

Comment: [In some places this is called the "term test"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test). I have to say it's a bad exam/class that rejects a correct answer on the basis that it's not on a pre-defined list of answers.

Comment: But this is the easiest test of all: the nth term test for divergence.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to find that if I make the numerator n^2 then put the whole thing in a radical, then divide all terms by n^2, I would get limit for the radical of 1/(1+(1/n^2)) and 1/n^2 is zero in the limit so just radical of 1/1 which is 1. And 1 does not equal 0 so it diverges.